# How can I execute a bunch of editor commands stored in a file in VIM?

Tags: regex, vim, automation, vi, scripting

I have read the other posts, e.g., [vim: Executing a list of editor commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830886/vim-executing-a-list-of-editor-commands) and others. The answer isn't clear to me for my case. I have some editor commands that I generated from an SQL query. It uses :s/foo/bar to change country codes (from FIPS to a non-standard code set). Here's a sample of the file:

```
:s/CB/CAMBO
:s/CQ/NMARI
:s/KV/KOSOV
:s/PP/PAPUA
...
```

I have saved that in a file called fipsToNonStd.vim (unsure about the correct extension). I want to run those commands one after another. What's the easiest way to do so?

Thanks a bunch! SO Rocks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `:source` command.

There is [online documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#:source) that you can see in vim by running `:help :source`.

Answer (score 3):

In general you'd want to just put all those commands into a .vim file. For instance you could save them in a file called *convert.vim*:

```
:%s/CD/CAMBO/g
:%s/CQ/NMARI/g
" etcetera
```

At this point you can load whatever file into Vim and type the following in your editor:

```
:so convert.vim
```

Alternately, if this is something you need to do in a pretty scripted basis, then why bother even opening vim? Do it all command line. You could do that by doing something like the following. Modify *convert.vim* again:

```
:%s/CD/CAMBO/g
:%s/CQ/NMARI/g
" etcetera
:w!
:q
```

Then you could just do it all on the command line. Suppose your 'input file' that requires conversion is called *data.txt*. From the command line you could do:

```
vim -s convert.vim data.txt
```

This would process/convert your data for you and save and be done.

Answer (score 1):

:source fileName

Answer (score 0):

You can put those lines into a function to be called later with :call FName